# make python request with requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to convert this curl command to python code:

```
Curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "http://blablabla.com"
```

I converted to this:

```
requests.get("http://blablabla.com", data={'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token}).json()
```

But i have error "Access denied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `Authorization` token inside the `headers`:

```
requests.get("http://blablabla.com", headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token}).json()
```